# Является ли BEGIN-END блок атомарной транзакцией?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transaction

Ответ может быть легко найти, но не нашёл.

Когда есть блок `BEGIN-END` в PL/SQL, ведет ли он себя как атомарная транзакция, которая пытается зафиксировать изменения по достижении `END` блока, а если что-то пойдет не так, то откатит изменения?

Если нет, то как убедиться, что код внутри блока `BEGIN-END` ведет себя как атомарная транзакция? И как блок ведет себя "по умолчанию"?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [BEGIN - END block atomic transactions in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11966020) от участника [@Jan Kratochvil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404764/jan-kratochvil)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11966020

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, `BEGIN-END` это всего лишь синтаксические элементы, они не имеют никакого отношения к транзакциям.

Во-вторых, в Oracle БД все отдельные DML являются атомарными, т.е. они либо заканчиваются успехом в полном объеме, либо будет откат любых промежуточных изменений при первой ошибке (если только, не используется опция `EXCEPTIONS INTO`, о которой здесь не буду углубляться).

Если нужно, чтобы группа DML рассматривалась как единая атомная транзакция, то надо сделать что-то подобное:

```
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT start_trans;
    INSERT INTO .... ; -- 1-й DML
    UPDATE .... ; -- 2-й DML
    BEGIN ... END; -- что-то еще в блоке
    UPDATE .... ; -- последний DML
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK TO start_trans;
    RAISE;
END;
```

Таким образом, любое исключение приведёт к откату всех DML в этом блоке, но любые изменения, которые были произведены *до этого блоке*, не откатяться.

Заметте, что `COMMIT` не включен, т.к. последнее слово, фиксировать изменения или нет, должно осаться  вызывающему процессу.

---

Это действительно так, что блок `BEGIN-END` без обработчика исключений неявно выполнит эту работу:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO .... ;
    UPDATE .... ;
    BEGIN ... END;
    UPDATE .... ;
END;
```

Если будет исключение, все вставки и обновления будут откачены. Но как только добавить обработчик исключений, то отката не произойдёт. Поэтому, предпочтельно явно обрабатывать исключения с использованием точек сохранения траннзакции.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11979726/6571020) от участника [@Jeffrey Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp)</sub>